# dinamixel Ubuntu and ROS version?

Tags: ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI !

Could anyone let me know, what version of Ubuntu and ROS do I need, for working with AX-12A Dinamixel motors?

Best

Mario

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285732/dinamixel-ubuntu-and-ros-version?/) by [marbulu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34191/marbulu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

you can use [dynamixel_motor](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_motor) ,in this  [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials/ConnectingToDynamixelBus) describes how to connect and examine raw feedback from Robotis Dynamixel servos.
you can use this package via ros kinetic jade indigo hydro .... i

i suggest you ubuntu 16.04 + kinetic

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2018-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marbulu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34191/marbulu/) on 2018-03-18**:
Great!
Thanks